# Xcode 4.2 not running my app after rebuilding MacBook (Snow Leopard)

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode4.2, storyboard

I recently had the MacBook I'm using to develop an app (for work) rebuilt. Xcode failed to launch and there were a number of issues when running 'verify permissions' on the disk. I copied the project to a USB stick and prepared to have the machine re-imaged. Now I have it back, I've re-installed Xcode, copied my project over and it opens - great. I started some alterations to the storyboard and tried to run it in the simulator, at which point it seems to crash and returns me to the Xcode window, debugger running.

I've tried to step through the 'problems' but I can't find anything wrong. This was a working, simple project (based entirely on a storyboard approach, very little code yet as I've been building an interface that was acceptable) and the storyboard still opens fine, all the segue's seem intact etc. It just won't run. I've tried it on another MacBook (running Lion) and it also failed, complaining about 'NSBundle' and 'MainStoryboard' (I'm sorry, that machine is at home and I don't have the exact message) - yet for all intents and purposes looked fine.

The build settings etc all verify and it builds with no issues. The app is stored in a different location on the disk to where it was originally, so perhaps some of that information is stored somewhere and needs to be reset? I've tried this: [XCode 4.2 MainStoryBoard Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113329/xcode-4-2-mainstoryboard-not-found) with no change.

Short of me scrapping this and starting afresh, is there anything I can do/try to salvage it? It's not a huge amount of work (probably a day or so, mainly adding text/images to the views) but I'd like to try and save it, hopefully understand a bit more of what's happened? Short of thinking the drive was corrupted and also corrupted the project somehow before I made the backup I'm at a loss.

Any pointers appreciated!

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'MainStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle </Users/appdev/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/82547437-7BE3-4960-B755-84E0A999A881/testApp.app> (loaded)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13be052 0x154fd0a 0x439352 0x151c9 0x15461 0x147c0 0x23743 0x241f8 0x17aa9 0x12a8fa9 0x13921c5 0x12f7022 0x12f590a 0x12f4db4 0x12f4ccb 0x142a7 0x15a9b 0x208d 0x1ff5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Comment: Update your xcode to 4.3.1 it will auto import and update you to llvm

Comment: Unfortunately on the work's MacBook I can't as it's Snow Leopard, and 4.3.1 only works on Lion. I do have 4.3.1 on my Mac at home though and had the same issue.

Comment: post your error logs and console logs for xcode crashing....

Comment: I've added what I'm presented with after the simulator 'crashes'. Xcode says it's attaching the app, it appears to launch then I'm back at the Xcode window and the above is in the 'all output' window for Thread 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the following settings in the xcode: and make sure to clean before building the app and running.

http://postimage.org/image/nk91mrlt9/ 
http://postimage.org/image/i3kd4zbqv/

Comment: Well, that seems to have done it. More specifically, the 'clean' part. I'm not totally convinced it was that, I did a load of things before a clean/build. But it works now!! :D Many thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

The storyboard file doesn't seem to be getting put into your application bundle.  Select it in the project navigator in the left-hand panel, and check that there is stick against the target in the file inspector in the right-hand panel.

Also, it sounds like you are not using version control.  Use version control!  If you had been using version control, you wouldn't have had to worry about moving the files from computer to computer, you could roll back to a working version, and you could easily see what the differences are between the old working version and the new broken version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Jim. There is a tick in the file inspector. I've also upgraded Xcode on my MacBook at home to the latest and it fails there, too (same initial error). As for version control, no I haven't enabled it as yet as this was my first real foray into storyboarding. Not overly convinced just yet...!