# After booting the launch Image resizes to half the width and won't disappear

Tags: ios, ios6

I have a strange issue.

After my App reboots, my Launch Image won't disappear and my initial view of my Main Storyboard won't show.
Instead of disappearing the launch image resizes to half the width...

This started happening after I added a launch image.
When I manually remove the launch image, it doesn't matter, the App still shows the launch image, even after removing it from XCode.

Here is screenshots of what is happening:

[image: Normal Launch image]

[image: After booting]

Anyone seen this before and knows how to fix this?

EDIT: (Additional info)
I could no longer select my main storyboard in the project summary. 
All other storyboards were visible but not the main storyboard.

Also as a result of that, the app was working fine in debugger, but it would crash straight away when it was distributed over TestFlight. I wouldn't even get TestFlight logs. The following CrashReport on the device directed me into the right way:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x3235029e __exceptionPreprocess + 158
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x39fce97a objc_exception_throw + 26
2   UIKit                           0x344e537c +[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:] + 436
3   UIKit                           0x3432758e -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 38
4   UIKit                           0x341b079c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 524
5   UIKit                           0x34158c34 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1000
6   UIKit                           0x341586c8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 68
7   UIKit                           0x34158116 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6150
8   GraphicsServices                0x35e4a59e _PurpleEventCallback + 586
9   GraphicsServices                0x35e4a1ce PurpleEventCallback + 30
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3232516e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 30
11  CoreFoundation                  0x32325112 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
12  CoreFoundation                  0x32323f94 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
13  CoreFoundation                  0x32296eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
14  CoreFoundation                  0x32296d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
15  UIKit                           0x341af480 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
16  UIKit                           0x341ac2fc UIApplicationMain + 1116
17  visitconnect-ios                0x00047e82 main (main.m:16)
18  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a405b1c start + 0
```

Comment: I think it is problem with Autolayout and wrong Constraints in your Storyboard file.

Comment: I had a look but cannot find anything. I cleared the initial storyboard view completely, but that didn't help much.. Any advise what I can look at? How come the Launch Image is still visible eventhough I removed it from XCode? Is there a way to make sure all references to the images are removed?

Comment: Maybe it was cached? Try Product > Clean and restart Xcode.

Comment: I think I found it, the default images did not have the right size, because I exported them again from Photoshop with the wrong dimensions (no retina dimensions but old iphone dimensions). After re-exporting the images, it seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where I found the answer:

[XCode 4.2 MainStoryBoard Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113329/xcode-4-2-mainstoryboard-not-found)

The reference to my MainStoryboard file somehow got corrupted.
This wasn't showing in the Simulator (other than the above symptoms) but when distributing the App over TestFlight, it would crash the App even before [TestFlight takeoff:] took place (meaning I had no logging at all in TestFlight).

I had to delete the references to the original MainStoryBoard.storyboard and put it back in the project by dragging it from finder back into xcode

Seems a bit lame to answer my own question, but anyway, for other people who might run into the same problem, hopefully this points you in the right direction.